# how to do this bootstrap search box in center with fully responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make below search box with select box in center of the page and all the field are stick to each other. I tried using margin-left. But i think this is not proper way to do this. please help me to do this to get all are in center with responsive.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<div class="col-md-12">
  
   <form action="#" method="get" id="search_mini_form">
      <div class="col-md-1 catnames">
         <select name="cat" class=" search-categories">
            <option>Categories</option>
            <option value="3">abcd</option>
            <option value="4">abcd</option>
            <option value="5">abcd</option>
         </select>
     
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 catnames catnames-arrow ">
         <select name="cat" class="search-categories search-Hourly">
            <option>Hourly</option>
            <option value="3">abcd</option>
            <option value="4">abcd</option>
            <option value="5">abcd</option>
         </select>
       
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 catquery">
   
         <input type="search" class="form-control " name="q" id="location" value="" maxlength="128" placeholder="Search Place..." autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 catsubmit">
         <div class="row">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
   </form>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    
    </style>

    <div class="col-md-12 ">
      <div class="row">
       <form action="#" method="get" id="search_mini_form">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 catnames">
             <select name="cat" class="form-control search-categories">
                <option>Categories</option>
                <option value="3">abcd</option>
                <option value="4">abcd</option>
                <option value="5">abcd</option>
             </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 catnames catnames-arrow ">
             <select name="cat" class="form-control search-categories search-Hourly">
                <option>Hourly</option>
                <option value="3">abcd</option>
                <option value="4">abcd</option>
                <option value="5">abcd</option>
             </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 catquery ">
       <div class="input-group">
             <input type="search" class="form-control " name="q" id="location" value="" maxlength="128" placeholder="Search Place..." autocomplete="off" />
         <div class="input-group-addon catsubmit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
       </form>
       </div>
    </div>
```

here is [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/heratosato/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: but also i want in desktop version all are in center with stick to each other verticaly. got it?

Comment: nope.. do you mean that all should be in single line? I guess you should understand `col-sm-`, `col-md-`, etc.. from getbootstrap.com

Comment: yes. I want to all be in single line only in desktop version and also no gap between all this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by applying some Bootstrap classes

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<div class="col-md-12">
  
   <form action="#" method="get" id="search_mini_form">
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 form-group col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12 catnames">
         <select name="cat" class="form-control search-categories">
            <option>Categories</option>
            <option value="3">abcd</option>
            <option value="4">abcd</option>
            <option value="5">abcd</option>
         </select>
     
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 form-group catnames catnames-arrow ">
         <select name="cat" class="form-control search-categories search-Hourly">
            <option>Hourly</option>
            <option value="3">abcd</option>
            <option value="4">abcd</option>
            <option value="5">abcd</option>
         </select>
       
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 form-group col-xs-12 catquery">
   <div class="input-group">
     <input type="search" class="form-control " name="q" id="location" value="" maxlength="128" placeholder="Search Place..." autocomplete="off" class="form-control" >
    <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
     </span> 
   </div>
      </div>
    
      <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
   </form>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change classes of whole container:

```
<div class="col-md-12 ">
```

to:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
```

You can also add styles for every element inside, like this:

```
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little fiddle to demonstrate how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/2nhzytu5/

To make the fields float in the center regardless desktop or mobile version, you can use `col-offset-xx` (Learn more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid))

Then, to make them stick together, you should use bootstrap's `input-group` class. (More info [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/) )

So this would be your base:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-group">
         <!-- Your fields here -->
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now simply add your fields:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">

      <select id="yourId" class="selectpicker form-control" title="Please select">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>

      <select id="yourId2" class="selectpicker form-control" title="Please select">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snpid" placeholder="Test">

      <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

> Avoid using  elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.